# If-Else/Function Debugging

Tags: r, function, debugging, if-statement, vector

R beginner here. I'm trying to create a function that converts values for a list in R using if-else. I'm pretty sure I'm violating some cardinal rule(s) with syntax/logic in R and I've read several manuals/online help tools for functions and if/else statements, but I cannot identify what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I am working with:

```
convTemp <- function(vector, to="Celsius"){
  if (to = "Celsius" ) { 
  return (vector - 32) * 5/9 
} 
 else
 print (vector) 
}
```

Any help/suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to define a function for this, just use base R's `ifelse()`:

```
temp_in_celsius <- ifelse(to == "Celsius", (vector - 32) * 5/9, vector)
```

As for what you are doing wrong, `to = "Celsius"` is an *assignment*, not an equality expression.  You probably intended to do `if (to == "Celsius") {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

In R, checking equality requires two equal signs "==".
Change the if statement to the following:

```
if (to == "Celsius" )
```